# winapi c++ HICON

Tags: c++, winapi, icons

I use minGW and eclipse.
And I made the HICON in this way:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
...
hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, "icon.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
if(hIcon) { SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon); }
else { MessageBoxW(hwnd, "ico not found", "ico not found", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR); }
...
}
```

So in this way the .ico must be in the same folder as the .exe
How can I build this .ico in to the exe?

Comment: A resource file would probably be easiest.

Comment: Yes, I type this line into my .rc file: 1 ICON "icon.ico" but this is not the same as HICON, and if I use HICON "icon.ico" nothing happens

Comment: You store the *icon* in the executable as a resource by using an 'ICON' directive in your resource script, and then use `LoadImage` to load the icon and obtain an `HICON` to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an .rc file to add the .ico file to your executable's resources.  Then when calling `LoadImage()`, get rid of the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag and specify the ID of your resource in the `lpszName` parameter instead of a filename.  For example:

```
MY_ICON ICON "icon.ico"
```

.

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
...
hIcon = (HICON) LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "MY_ICON", IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0);
...
}
```

Comment: Remember to use `TEXT("MY_ICON")` to make it work when compiling for Unicode.  Also make sure you're using the right HINSTANCE.  The GetModuleHandle will work fine if everything is in the same executable, but if the loading code is in a DLL and the icon is in the EXE's resources (or vice versa), you'll have to choose the HINSTANCE more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

You can use resource files.

See here for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zabda143(v=vs.71).aspx